# Inheritance without containing?

Tags: c++

I have class A. And I have class B. And I have many-many classes derived from class B.

I want to achieve this: derivatives of B should have access to the protected variables of A. Whithout each of them containing an instance of A, which would need a lot of memory.
So I guess public inheritance is not a good idea this time. How do I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with `friend` and accessor functions. This does trust `B` to stay off `A`'s privates - don't see a good way to let *only* `B` and subclasses access *only* protected members of `A` unless there's an inheritance relationship between `A` and `B`.

```
class A {
friend class B;
protected:
  int X;
};


class B {
protected:
  static int getX(A const & a) { return a.X; }
};

class C : public B {
public:
  void foo(A const & a) { int bar = getX(a); }
};
```

Comment: I would do the same, but I would prefer `static int getX` because in its logic getX does not pertain to an instance of B. **Edit**: Having to do this at all sounds like bad design in the first place.

Comment: To allow `B` to access only `A`'s protected members, you could derive a proxy class from `A`, and make `B` a friend of that instead.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: As I understand the OP he already has existing instances of A - if he's free to replace use of A with the proxy class, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Make the classes that are derived from B friends of A.

Comment: All of them? And if I make a new class derived from B, I should add that to the list of friends in class A? I want to make it expandable. And friends do have access even for private, which is not needed.

Comment: If you want that many classes to have access to A's private members then either they should be public members or you should use public accessors. Either way, it's a sign that you should rethink your design.

Comment: Yes, all of them. If the class derived of B could decide to be a friend of A, it would circumvent information hiding. On the other hand, the solution of Erik might be better.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand children of `B` are unrelated to class `A` and as such *should not have access to non-public parts of `A`*.

The right way to get access to `A`'s data within `B` child classes is through `A`'s public interface. If such public interface isn't adequate then that's a signal that either you're trying to do something that's a poor design, or that `A`'s public interface needs to be improved.